# Failing to declare Var in global scope

Tags: javascript, scope, indexeddb

I want to change entries of an indexedDB. So having values in an inputfield and submitting them to an existing db entry, and later retrieving them before editing them again.

Right now the script wont work because: Uncaught TypeError: db is undefined

By pressing a button a function gets called that itself calls a function.
Buttonpressfunction `$('#edit-button').click` --> "updateMarma" --> uses "getObjectStore" --> this needs the "db" variable declared.

At first I accidently put everything in "open.onsuccess = function() {" there the db variable was accessible. But to make it work the functions need to be by them self. But now I cannot figgure out how to / where to declare db.

I also tried within `open.onupgradeneeded = function() {` `db = open.result;` but this still not made it global.
I also tried IEF.
I can't find any other hints in documentation, help would be much apriciated.

```
(function() {
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;
var db;
    // Open (or create) the database
    var open = indexedDB.open("marmaDB", 1);
    console.log("open Db ...");

    // Create the schema
    console.log("creating schema ...");
    open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = open.result;
        var store = db.createObjectStore("marmasStore", {keyPath: "id"});
        var index = store.createIndex("NameIndex", ["name.last", "name.first"]);
            store.createIndex('sanskrit', 'sanskrit', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('marmaGrp', 'marmaGrp', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('location', 'location', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('localisation', 'localisation', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('awareness', 'awareness', { unique: false });
            store.createIndex('frequency', 'frequency', { unique: false });
      };

    function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
        var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(store_name);
    }

    open.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log("open DB DONE");
        // Start a new transaction
        var db = open.result;
        var tx = db.transaction("marmasStore", "readwrite");
        var store = tx.objectStore("marmasStore");
        var index = store.index("NameIndex");

        // Add some data
        const initialMarmaData = [
            { id: "ani_ll", sanskrit: "ani", name: "Ani", marmaGrp: "snayu", location: "linker Oberschenkel", localisation: 0, awareness: 0, frequency: 0 },
            { id: "ani_rl", sanskrit: "ani", name: "Ani", marmaGrp: "snayu", location: "rechter Oberschenkel", localisation: 0, awareness: 0, frequency: 0 },
            { id: "ani_la", sanskrit: "ani", name: "Ani", marmaGrp: "snayu", location: "linker Arm", localisation: 0, awareness: 0, frequency: 0 },
            { id: "ani_ra", sanskrit: "ani", name: "Ani", marmaGrp: "snayu", location: "rechter Arm", localisation: 0, awareness: 0, frequency: 0 },
        ];

        // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
        // put overwrites date in DB
        // add can only be done once , second time script just stops.
        console.log("initial filling DB ...");
        var store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');
        initialMarmaData.forEach((marma) => {
            var request = store.put(marma); // maybe change to add and programm errorhandler
            request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                console.log(event.target.result + " initial filling DB DONE");
            };
        });
        
        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        tx.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
            console.log("closing DB DONE");
        };
      }

    // Query the data
    function updateMarma(key) {
        console.log("updatePublication:", arguments);
        console.log("key:", key);
        if (typeof store == 'undefined')
            store = getObjectStore("marmasStore", 'readwrite');

        var marmaInfo = store.get(key);
        marmaInfo.onsuccess = function(evt) {
            console.log(key + " FOUND");
            var record = evt.target.result;
            console.log("record:", record);
            if (typeof record == 'undefined') {
                displayActionFailure("No matching record found");
                return;
            }
            console.log("Name for id is  + ${marmaInfo.result.name}");
            alert("ID " + marmaInfo.result.id + " sanskrit " + marmaInfo.result.sanskrit);
        };
    }
      
    $('#edit-button').click(function(evt) {
        console.log("edit ...");
        var key = $('#marmaID').val();

        var new_bodylocation = $('#bodylocation').val();
        var new_awareness = $('#awareness').val();
        if (key != '') {
            console.log("editing " + key);
            updateMarma(key);
        } else {
            console.log("no key provided");
            displayActionFailure("Invalid key")
            return;
        }
    });

})();
```

Comment: Don't use `var` when you want to assign the global variable. `var db = open.result;` should just be `db = open.result;`

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried that, but this did not work

Comment: You have that in multiple places, did you fix them all?

Comment: Are you seeing the `open DB DONE` message?

Comment: @corbinian, this is a classic case of unintended shadowing. The MDN example for describing the var keyword illustrates your exact problem with brilliant succinctness. The var keyword, on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var to clarify, variable shadowing is when you redeclare a variable at one level, but then while that declaration is still in scope, you fully redeclare it in another scope. What Barmar is suggesting is that you leave "var db" on line 2, but then change every following use from `var db = ...` to 'db = ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Barmar indeed i missed one line, now it works.
SamHughes thanks for the link very good :)
Because itsjust comments I cant upvote or set right answer, right? How can I mark this as solved?